# Spinner drop down menu items color (Android)

Tags: android-spinner, textcolor

So I have a spinner and I was successful in changing the color of the selected item but I am not able to change the color of the items in the drop down menu

This is my **spinner_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView  
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="13sp" 
   android:textColor="#33CCFF"         
/>
```

and this is my **styles.xml**

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" >
     <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem.DropDownItem.Color</item>
     <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
  </style>
  <style name="SpinnerItem.DropDownItem.Color" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
      <item name="android:textColor">#4FBDE8</item>
  </style>

  <style name="SpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
      <item name="android:textColor">#4FBDE8</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

is there an XML way I can do it in ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution I found on another stackoverflow thread

```
<style name="Theme.NoTitleBar.WithColoredSpinners" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem.DropDownItem</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItem.DropDownItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

While specifying a layout resource file for the spinner, you have to set it at two places.

1. While declaring a new ArrayAdapter

   ```
   ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, categories);
   ```
2. While setting the dropDownViewResource on the array adapter.

   ```
   dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item_dropdown);
   ```

Notice that two different layout files have been used. You can customize your views in the following manner, by defining the styles and using these styles as theme in the respective layouts.

```
<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItem.DropDownItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked for me. Could you tell the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: Nothing really happens, the text color not the back ground changes

Comment: Post your code here. Most probably you are not using the styles correctly.

Comment: So, I made all according to your answer , but I don't understand exactly, where I need to set this custom style... In TextView from `R.layout.spinner_item_dropdown` ?